# Editing grouped data change rows order

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview

```
<t:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" Name="gridView" />

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Row Order Checker");
        dt.Columns.Add("Group by me");
        dt.Columns.Add("Data for editing");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "data 1");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "data 2");
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "data 3");

        gridView.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    }
```

I've added simple telerik grid on form. 
Then I grouped data by "Group by me" column.
Then I edited first row and changed "data 1" to "qwe".
Row moved at the end of grouped data.

How to avoid this strange behaiour? I want row to stay at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Add an auto-incremental column. Order the rows also along with Group By and I think you are missing Using statement?

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is not a strange behavior. Its actually sorting on the columns with its default algorithm. In order to achieve your scenario you would need to modify the code as below:

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="True" Name="gridView">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding GroupByMe}" Header="Group By Me"   />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding DataForEditing}" Header="Data For Editing" />
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Row Order Checker");
dt.Columns.Add("Identifier", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("GroupByMe");
dt.Columns.Add("DataForEditing");

dt.Rows.Add(1, "1", "data 1");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "1", "data 2");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "1", "data 3");

SortDescriptor sortDescriptor = new SortDescriptor();
sortDescriptor.Member = "Identifier";
sortDescriptor.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
gridView.SortDescriptors.Add(sortDescriptor);

gridView.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

Changes i have made are:

- Introduce a unique identifier column
- add a sort descriptor on the Identifier column
- on the ui do not show the identifier column

With the above code when you group by "GroupByMe" column, it will still be sorting on the identifier column.  since the identifier is not shown and it remains unchanged, the edited row stays as is without changing its position

Hope this answers your question.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)

Comment: But without grouping rows don't jump. Why grouping adds sorting? Is it normal? Your solution is ugly for me. But if there is no other solution I'll accept this solution :(

Comment: Telerik's example "Row Number" works as I expect. Is it also normal? :)

Comment: For 2012 version all examples work as I expect. Is it released version or CTP? P.S. I use version 2011.